# I can not make a request and the Response to a servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, httpsession

I have a servlet. in it I form a line and when I type in the browser link, he told me that rotates the line. everything is fine. Now I want to create an array of strings, and depending on the parameter in the link rotates the particular row. how to do it?

```
@WebServlet("/goods")
public class GoodsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("{\"name\":\"Pavel\",\"sname\":\"Petrashov\",\"age\":24,\"params\":{\"heigth\":188, \"weight\":72, \"strong\":100}}");
    }
}
```

and I want to have

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("{\"name\":\"Pavel\",\"sname\":\"Petrashov\",\"age\":24,\"params\":{\"heigth\":188, \"weight\":72, \"strong\":100}}");
        list.add("{\"name\":\"Bill\",\"sname\":\"Gey\",\"age\":99,\"params\":{\"heigth\":188, \"weight\":70, \"strong\":100}}");
        list.add("{\"name\":\"Uill\",\"sname\":\"Smitt\",\"age\":12,\"params\":{\"heigth\":188, \"weight\":99, \"strong\":100}}");
```

and to make sure that my reference `http://localhost:666/sg/goods`took some parameter, depending on which will return an array element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean depending on GET parameters you want to print out one of the strings in the list? If that is what you want then 
`String myParameter = request.getParameter("param");`
will give you the get parameter. Pass the parameter as a query string on the url like `http://localhost:666/sg/goods?param=2`.

Now use the parameter to get the string from your list

`try{
    int index = Integer.parseInt(myParameter);
    out.println(list.get(index));
 } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException|NumberFormatException ex){
    System.err.println("Invalid get parameter");
 }`

Comment: I just did what you said earlier, but the answer is correct, and I checked. thank you!